# Registration and retrieving COM object from .Net 6 DLL (Typelib export: Type library is not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131165))

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, com, typelib

I register COM object from .Net 6 DLL using following script `.\regsvr32.exe .\MyLibrary.comhost.dll`
In addition, in the DLL, it registers itself in ROT via         `[DllImport("oleaut32.dll")] internal extern static int RegisterActiveObject([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object punk, ref Guid rclsid, uint dwFlags, ref int pdwRegister);`
After I can get this object using `Marshal.GetActiveObject("MyLibrary.MyClassName")`, I can get the object, but
`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Typelib export: Type library is not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131165)'` exception is thrown when I try to call a method from this object. Could you help to resolve the issue, please?

Comment: To oversimplify (depends on details) you need to build and register a type library (a .TLB or a .TLB binary embedded as a resource in a .DLL or .EXE) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com#embedding-type-libraries-in-the-com-host Note: .NET Core will not help to build it , you can only embed it. To build it you will have to use MIDL from a .IDL file (or reuse one built from a .NET Framework COM object & regasm /tlb) You can have a look a this sample https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/samples/out-of-process-com-server/

Comment: @SimonMourier I generated the .TLB file using dSPACE.Runtime.InteropServices.BuildTasks and registered it using 'dscom tlbregister fileName.tlb'. Then according to documentation I added ' <ComHostTypeLibrary Include="MyFile.tlb" Id="1" />' and I still have the error.

Comment: That info belongs in the question.  You are giving conflicting commands, the dscom command says that the type library is stored in the .tlb file, ComHostTypeLibrary says that it is embedded in the comhost.  It also isn't obvious if they write the 32-bit or 64-bit registry key.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to see what actually happens.

Comment: I don't know this tool but some simple test indicates it has serious limitation, IMHO you should use a .IDL file and midl or provide a full reproducing simple project.

Comment: @SimonMourier I'm stuck on it. Here are the test projects: https://files.fm/u/z5y9fyg4pk

Comment: @Serhii - My PC tells me there are virus in there, just put source code w/o compiled binaries

Comment: @SimonMourier I replied below

Comment: Please post somewhere (github, whatever) a reproducing project w/o all binaries instead of answering yourself with code that we'll have to copy paste

Comment: @SimonMourier https://files.fm/u/b8hmdu9n8g

Comment: This is because Microsoft has removed the implementation of ITypeInfo in .NET core https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/86751 which is what `dynamic` counts on undercover. It can work 1) if your host is .NET Framework, not Core or 2) if you cast the object as `ICalculator` (with tlb registered) or 3) if you use the raw reflection way: `var sum = obj.GetType().InvokeMember("myadd", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, new object[] { 5, 6 });` For 1 and 3) you don't even need a registered tlb since it's pure `IDispatch` based.

Comment: @SimonMourier I am very grateful to you. Could you tell me how exactly I can cast the object as ICalculator (with tlb registered)?

Comment: Just declare `ICalculator` in your `callingproj` project (you can create a common .cs file so you can share the source of interfaces in all projects) and do this `var calc = (ICalculator)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Library1.Calculator");var sum = calc.myadd(5, 6);` It it works, just tell me I will write a detailed answer

Comment: @SimonMourier I try to do it and have the following error System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
Could you write a detailed answer, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is Microsoft has removed support for [ITypeInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-itypeinfo) from the [COM Callable wrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/com-callable-wrapper) implementation in .NET Core (all versions), the object which also implements [IDispatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-idispatch). This is briefly discussed here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/86751 and in fact mentioned in documentation:

[image]

Contrary to what the github discussion seems to imply, this is a big breaking change that causes lots of trouble, which is difficult to diagnose, and has no easy solution.

The `ITypeInfo` reference is retrieved by the `dynamic` code using [IDispatch::GetTypeInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nf-oaidl-idispatch-gettypeinfo) when you try to call any member by a name (such as `myadd`) on your object:

> Retrieves the type information for an object, which can then be used
> to get the type information for an interface.
>
> HRESULT GetTypeInfo(
> UINT      iTInfo,
> LCID      lcid,
> ITypeInfo **ppTInfo
> );

Now, to add to the problem, your calling code is .NET Framework, and the `dynamic` implementation is different between the two:

.NET Framework (throws even if type info count = 0):

```
internal static ITypeInfo GetITypeInfoFromIDispatch(IDispatch dispatch, bool throwIfMissingExpectedTypeInfo)
{
  int errorCode = dispatch.TryGetTypeInfoCount(out var pctinfo);
  Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(errorCode); // noooooooo !
  if (pctinfo == 0)
    return null;
  ...
}
```

This is what ultimately causes the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Typelib export: Type library is not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131165)'` error

.NET Core (more recent, less stupid):

```
internal static ComTypes.ITypeInfo GetITypeInfoFromIDispatch(IDispatch dispatch)
{
    int hresult = dispatch.TryGetTypeInfoCount(out uint typeCount);
    if (typeCount == 0)
    {
        // COM objects should return a type count of 0 to indicate that type info is not exposed.
        // Some COM objects may return a non-success HRESULT when type info is not supported, so
        // we only check the count and not the HRESULT in this case.
        return null;
    }

    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hresult); // yeeeeeees !
    ...
}
```

There are multiple solutions:

**IDispatch based:** If you want to continue using `dynamic`, you can either use a .NET Core client or use the "old" reflection way, like this (doesn't uses `ITypeInfo`, goes directly to `IDispatch` `GetIDsOfNames` and `Invoke`):

```
var sum = obj.GetType().InvokeMember(
    "myadd",
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
    null,
    obj,
    new object[] { 5, 6 });
```

**IUnknown based:** Since you have defined a dual `ICalculator` interface (`IDispatch` + `IUnknown`-derived), you can use it instead of using a late-bound (`IDispatch`) approach.

For that, the system must know the details of that interface to be able to marshal it across threads/processes/machines, ie: it needs a .TLB (also make sure you stick to [already known data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/marshaling-ole-data-types) or you'll need a proxy / stub .dll which is out of .NET reach). So you must 1) export a `.TLB` (a Type Library file, you can also embed it in a .dll or a .exe) from the .NET Code and 2) register it, using for example [dscom](https://github.com/dspace-group/dscom), an unofficial tool which does work fine with this sample code (Microsoft has also removed the .TLB generation and registration facility that existed in `regasm` for .NET Framework). Make sure you build everything in x64 and use dscom for x64 too (not x86), something like this:

```
dscom.exe tlbexport c:\temp\core dll\bin\Debug\net6.0\Library1.dll
dscom.exe tlbregister Library1.tlb
```

and then change your calling .NET Framework code like this:

```
var calc = (ICalculator)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Library1.Calculator");
var res = calc.myadd(5, 6);
TextBox1.Text = res.ToString();
```

PS: There's another solution more complex which is to expose a wrapper on the object, on the .NET Core host side, instead of the object itself, that would reimplement `IDispatch` w/o reporting any error when .NET Framework calls `IDispatch::GetTypeInfo` and internally calls the object's `IDispatch` implementation